# Vertica/SQL, Case ELSE, Types numeric and boolean are inconsistent

Tags: sql, vertica

Hi I have the following query,

```
case when B.Name = 'stack' then M.type = 'Value EOD' else V.Value end as "Value USD"
```

I cannot get this case statement to work. Error msg `For 'case', types numeric and boolean are inconsistent`

Anyone help with this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to try to combine a boolean result and numeric value into a single column, particularly one called `Value USD`.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
(case when B.Name = 'stack' and M.type = 'Value EOD' then V.Value end) as "Value USD"
```

Rows that don't match the `when` condition would evaluate to `NULL`.